# How to do a group within a group in Mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a query where by:

```
 $offenses = \App\LawCase::raw(function ($collection)  {
                return $collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => ['active' => true, 'type' => 'criminal', 'current_offense_literal'=> ['$exists' => true]]
                    ],
                    [
                        '$group' => ['_id' => '$current_offense_category',
                            'offense_literals' => ['$addToSet' => '$current_offense_literal'], 'code'=> ['$addToSet' => '$current_offense'], 'count' => ['$sum' => 1]]
                    ]

                ]);


            });
```

It works fine but I want to get how many occurrences of a particular 'current_offense_literal' I got above. I guess a group within a group?

Comment: You can use `$size` operator to count the number of elements inside the `current_offense_literal`.

Comment: But its not an array. :(